# Chart won't refresh after export/import code

Tags: excel

using these code the chart display without a problem:

```
Sub graphit()

  On Error Resume Next
  Set CurrentChart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("spectralcht")
  On Error GoTo 0
  If IsEmpty(CurrentChart) Then
       ' init chart if first run
       Set speccht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=100, Width:=500, Top:=100, Height:=300)
       chtcount = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Count
       Set speccht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(chtcount)
       speccht.Name = "spectralcht"
       With speccht.Chart
         .ChartType = xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers 'Ensure chart has a title
         .HasTitle = True
         .ChartTitle.Text = "Spectrum (power vs Wavelength)"
         .Legend.Delete
         .Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = 0
         .Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 4000
         .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
         .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "WaveLength (nm)"
         .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
         .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Intencity"
         .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasMajorGridlines = True
         .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasMinorGridlines = True
         .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).MajorGridlines.Border.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
         .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).MajorGridlines.Border.LineStyle = xlDash
      End With
  End If

  'chage axe for new WL
  Set speccht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("spectralcht")
  With speccht.Chart
         .Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = CDbl(MinWL.Value)
         .Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = CDbl(MaxWL.Value)
  End With

  ' plot graph
  With speccht.Chart.SeriesCollection
      If .Count = 0 Then .NewSeries
      .Item(1).Values = Spectrum()
      .Item(1).XValues = Wavelengths()
  End With

End Sub
```

But if I export the form an i import on a other book it won't display the data!
It display chart, axes, but no data no graph.
I am a little lost at this point
merci in advance
pat

Comment: Have you stepped through your code? Do your two arrays have values?

Comment: Spectrum()  and Wavelenghts() have 2048 data in. it does read it in an other sub in the same form. when i run it, it step thru all line without error.

Comment: And have you stepped through the code to see if the lines that allocate the data are being run, and verified that you have the correct data in the arrays, not errors or zeroes? Is there a series added to the chart at the end?

Comment: Yes it does step through those lines, and yes the 2 array are valid

Comment: this sub work perfectly until i export the form and i inport it on an other book.

Comment: The code you posted can't really be at fault then as nothing in it is workbook specific. I'll ask again: does the chart have a data series on it after running the code? If so, what are the values? I will note that the length of a SERIES formula is limited, so assigning arrays directly to charts can be problematic; it's better to use ranges.

Comment: I do not comprehend the question. the data series is  " .Item(1).Values = Spectrum()"and ".Item(1).XValues = Wavelengths()" ?? as a new series?

Comment: I mean does the actual chart have any series assigned to it after running your code?

Comment: Before I export the form; yes I see my series in the graph.When I inport the form into a new excel book then i do not see the serie . even if i can see all element of the array using Watch expressions.

Comment: Just before ending the sub...   speccht.Chart.count  = 1 ...spectrum(1)=101....Wavelength(1)= 592.245..... Question : is .Item(1).value should take the entire array of 2047 element of spectrum() ?

Comment: If your data has a lot of decimals, you are extremely likely to run into the SERIES formula length limitations. Can you put the data into a range and refer to that instead?

Comment: Then why is it working good on the original book?

Comment: problem solve....I just use the original book (working one) copy sheet from wanted one into working one and save as....I do not use export form and import in wanted book.